# How to get element by class in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, android

```
@Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                setTitle(view.getTitle());
                view.loadUrl("javascript:function injek3(){window.hasdir=1;window.dir=function(n){var r=[];for(var t in n)'function'==typeof n[t]&&r.push(t);return r}};if(window.hasdir!=1){injek3();}");
                view.loadUrl("javascript:function injek2(){window.touchblock=0,window.dummy1=1,document.addEventListener('click',function(n){if(1==window.touchblock){n.preventDefault();n.stopPropagation();var t=document.elementFromPoint(n.clientX,n.clientY);window.ganti=function(n){t.outerHTML=n},window.gantiparent=function(n){t.parentElement.outerHTML=n},$$.print(t.parentElement.outerHTML, t.outerHTML)}},!0)}1!=window.dummy1&&injek2();");
                view.loadUrl("javascript:function injek(){window.hasovrde=1;var e=XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open=function(ee,nn,aa){this.addEventListener('load',function(){$$.log(this.responseText, nn, JSON.stringify(arguments))}),e.apply(this,arguments)}};if(window.hasovrde!=1){injek();}");
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }
        });
```

From the above example how to get data from element by a particular class,i.e getting data from particular element and getting output in Java.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you need to set the True setJavaScriptEnabled function in Webview setting like the below:

```
  webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
  WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
  webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

after that, you need to introduce your interface in android code :

```
  webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "MyAndroidInterface");
```

"MyAndroidInterface" will be used later to call functions in JavaScriptInterface later.

the JavaScriptInterface class :

```
 public class JavaScriptInterface {
     Context mContext;
     JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
         mContext = c;
     }
     //add other interface methods to be called from JavaScript
}
```

your HTML class can be like below :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getDataFunction(){
       //return value to Android 
       var val= document.ipForm.userName.value;
       MyAndroidInterface.receiveValueFromJs(val);
    }
    </script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body >
    <form name="ipForm" id="ipForm">
      UserName : <input type="text" name="userName">
      <button type="button" onclick="getDataFunction();">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

and finally, you can call the javaScript function like the below everywhere you want :

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:getDataFunction()");
```

then you need to add callback function in JavaScriptInterface that you called in HTML file

```
public void receiveValueFromJs(String str) {
//do something useful with str
  Toast.makeText(mContext, "Received Value from JS: " + str,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

it was so easy, right?

Comment: Skip the html part bro ! Now  Need to get tr(a tabletow) data from  a website which was not created by me